# The way I treat her mom

Tags: meaning, expressions, synonyms

I need a word  that I can use  in describing how I have always treated someone; a word that is basically a unique or rarely heard synonym for being respectful overly polite  courteous  and accommodating,  a great word  that displays my level of intelligence – to end the following sentence:

> Even though I find her to be an utterly despicable person,
>   I have always been respectful, polite, courteous, and ________?

Comment: Do you want a word that means respectful, overly polite, courteous and accommodating, or one that means respectful, overly polite, courteous and accommodating, but cynically so?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

There are a myriad synonyms you could choose from, such as civil, considerate, deferential, mannerly, etc.

However, using four consecutive synonyms (even when you're trying to emphasize a point) is rather verbose. If you really want to emphasize how friendly you have been with her, you could instead use words that have similar but different enough meanings to say something like

> Even though I find her to be an utterly despicable person, I have always been respectful, considerate, and amiable (towards her).

which conveys more information than just "overly polite".